# $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is integrable on $[a',b] \ \forall \ a'>a \in \Bbb R \implies f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have the following statement and i need to demonstrate it:
$$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb R \ \text{is bounded (on } [a,b] \text{) and integrable on} \ [a',b] \ \forall \ a'>a \in \Bbb R  \implies f \ \text{is integrable on} \ [a,b]$$

I tried to build a succession of integral when $a' \to a$ but in this kind of question I lack in formalism. The statement is clear and I've fully understood it but i'm not able to put down on paper in mathematical terms my reasoining. The function should be Riemann integrable and I know that probably it could be useful to use the Lebesgue-measure but unfortunately I don't know what it is and for this kind of exercise I'm not supposed to use it. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647134/99914)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't able to find this answer

Comment: The only reason I can find it is because I am the answer-er. It's hard to search in this site in general.

Comment: As more basic advice: to show rigorously that <X> has property <Y>, write down the definition of <Y> and see how <X> could satisfy that definition. Or use a theorem that gives you the property you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This was [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647058/how-to-show-that-this-modification-of-thomaes-function-is-riemann-integrable/1647134#1647134) posted in a quite different question. The answer is reposted here, in the hope that it is easier to be found).

To show that, let $\epsilon >0$. Then let $\delta < \epsilon/4C$, where $C$ is the bound of $f$. Since $f$ is integrable on $[a+\delta, b]$, there is a partition $P = \{\delta = x_1< x_2<\cdots< x_n = b\}$ of $[a+\delta, b]$ so that

$$U(P, f|_{[a+\delta, b]}) - L(P, f|_{[a+\delta, b]}) < \epsilon/2.$$

Let $\tilde P$ be the partition of $[a, b]$ given by

$$a = x_0< \delta = x_1 < x_2 <\cdots < x_n = b.$$

Then

$$\begin{split}
U(P, f) - L(P, f) &= (M-m) \delta + U(P, f|_{[a+\delta, b]}) - L(P, f|_{[a+\delta, b]})\\
&< 2C\delta + \epsilon /2 \\
&< \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon.
\end{split}
$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $f$ is integrable.

Remark:

One can indeed show that

$$\int_a^b f (x) dx = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \int_{a+\delta} ^b f(x)dx.$$

Comment: The last equation follows from the integrability of $f$ on $[a, b] $ which you have established earlier. By FTC the function $F$ given by $F(x) =\int_{x} ^{b} f(t) \, dt$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ provided $f$ is integrable on $[a, b] $.